# Array formulas based on another column

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I'm working with two Excel files. The first has an array formula.

`=IF(ISERR(INDEX('[Talent Biography Report Sample 8-8-18.xlsx]Leadership Training Info'!$A:$E,SMALL(IF('[Talent Biography Report Sample 8-8-18.xlsx]Leadership Training Info'!$A:$E=$B$1,ROW('[Talent Biography Report Sample 8-8-18.xlsx]Leadership Training Info'!$A:$E)),ROW(1:1)),5)),"",INDEX('[Talent Biography Report Sample 8-8-18.xlsx]Leadership Training Info'!$A:$E,SMALL(IF('[Talent Biography Report Sample 8-8-18.xlsx]Leadership Training Info'!$A:$E=$B$1,ROW('[Talent Biography Report Sample 8-8-18.xlsx]Leadership Training Info'!$A:$E)),ROW(1:1)),5))`

This array formula is calling another Excel file and comparing numbers in each row to see if they are a match. So basically, if `B1` in Excel file 1 matches `B2` in Excel file 2, then output `E2` (`E2` is a Time stamp date). Go to the next row and compare numbers and so on until `B1` does **not** match `B2`.

**I wanted `E2` which is the Time stamp to only show the date, i.e. `2/21/2012` and not `2/21/2012 11:00 AM EST`**, so I wrote this formula to strip the time stamp off.

`=(LEFT(E2,FIND("/",E2,FIND("/",E2)+1)-1)&"/"&IF(LEN(RIGHT(E2,LEN(E2)-SEARCH(" ",E2)))=12,LEFT(RIGHT(E2,17),4),LEFT(RIGHT(E2,16),4)))/1`

When I change the Array to output the date which is now `F2` the output is coming out as blank. I assume that arrays can't output values of a row where another formula is being used?

Comment: Are you referring to `Arrays` (ie VBA) or `Array Formulas`? Your question is very hard to understand. The goal is to include as little information as possible in order to clearly communicate the *specific* issue you're having - yet include *everything* required to replicate the problem.  Please see **how to create a [MCVE]** and [edit] your question to clarify with some examples of what you have, what you want to have, where you're stuck and what you've tried.

Comment: The first thing you should try when  having a problem with a **huge** formula is to break it up into several smaller formulas, each function if possible, to determine exactly where the problem is.  Nobody can take a look at that and know what's wrong, especially without seeing your data. You have about 15 functions you can break the above formulas into. For example, that do you expect `RIGHT(E2,16)` to return.. and what is it *actually* giving you? If it's correct then move on to `LEFT(RIGHT(E2,16),4)`. Is that section returning what you expect? etc etc.No idea why you have a `/1` there

Comment: Hold on, are you saying you wanted to change the date format so you used a big long formula to do that, and now Excel isn't recognizing it as a date??  I'd suggest starting with [an Excel tutorial](https://www.google.ca/search?q=beginner+excel+tutorial+formatting) or two.  Also this is not a programming question; this may be better suited to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).

Comment: you might want to look at the date function  `=DATE(year,month,day)` since you are stripping those components out you could drop them right into date.  Also look at whether or not `DATEVALUE` works for you in this case.

Comment: Please let us know what version of Excel you are using?

Comment: I'm using 2016.

Comment: Sorry, I never said it was a programming question, but it is an Array therefore I tagged it as one. My fault.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your month and its working for you.

```
LEFT(E2,FIND("/",E2,FIND("/",E2)+1)-1))
```

Assuming this is your year

```
IF(LEN(RIGHT(E2,LEN(E2)-SEARCH(" ",E2)))=12,LEFT(RIGHT(E2,17),4),LEFT(RIGHT(E2,16),4))
```

Assuming you are looking for the start of the month with

```
/1
```

Take each of those segments and drop it into the DATE function

```
DATE(year, month, day)
=DATE(IF(LEN(RIGHT(E2,LEN(E2)-SEARCH(" ",E2)))=12,LEFT(RIGHT(E2,17),4),LEFT(RIGHT(E2,16),4)),LEFT(E2,FIND("/",E2,FIND("/",E2)+1)-1)),1)
```

That would give you the first of each month if the above assumptions were correct.

Comment: Sorry if I made things complicated. I'm not having a problem with the date formula, I'm having a problem with the Array that calls on the date formula.

Comment: its sounded like your array formula worked at pulling the date into E2, but it screwed up when you applied the date conversion to it

Answer (score 0):

Although this array formula seems to be working, I would suggest some adjustment to improve its performance:

```
=IF( ISERR(
INDEX( '[Talent Biography Report Sample 8-8-18.xlsx]Leadership Training Info'!$A:$E,
SMALL( IF('[Talent Biography Report Sample 8-8-18.xlsx]Leadership Training Info'!$A:$E=$B$1,
ROW( '[Talent Biography Report Sample 8-8-18.xlsx]Leadership Training Info'!$A:$E) ),
ROW(1:1) ), 5 ) ), "",
INDEX('[Talent Biography Report Sample 8-8-18.xlsx]Leadership Training Info'!$A:$E,
SMALL( IF('[Talent Biography Report Sample 8-8-18.xlsx]Leadership Training Info'!$A:$E = $B$1, 
ROW('[Talent Biography Report Sample 8-8-18.xlsx]Leadership Training Info'!$A:$E)),
ROW(1:1)), 5 ) )
```

In order to ease the review of the array formula let’s summarized it by replacing `'[Talent Biography Report Sample 8-8-18.xlsx]Leadership Training Info'` with `'[Wb]Sh'`:

```
=IF( ISERR( 
INDEX( '[Wb]Sh'!$A:$E,  
SMALL( IF( '[Wb]Sh'!$A:$E = $B$1, ROW( '[Wb]Sh'!$A:$E) ), ROW(1:1) ), 5 ) ), "",  
INDEX( '[Wb]Sh'!$A:$E, 
SMALL( IF( '[Wb]Sh'!$A:$E = $B$1, ROW( '[Wb]Sh'!$A:$E) ), ROW(1:1) ), 5 ) )
```

This array formula can be improved by using the [WorksheetFunction.IfError Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-iferror-method-excel) as follows:

```
=IFERROR( INDEX( '[Wb]Sh'!$A:$E, 
SMALL( IF( '[Wb]Sh'!$A:$E = $B$1, ROW( '[Wb]Sh'!$A:$E) ), ROW(1:1) ), 5 ) ), "")
```

Further improvement can be achieved by reducing the arrays to the strictly necessary size:

```
=IFERROR( INDEX( '[Wb]Sh'!$E:$E, 
SMALL( IF( '[Wb]Sh'!$A:$A = $B$1, ROW( '[Wb]Sh'!$A:$A) ), ROW(1:1) ) ), "")
```

**Solution:**

This standard formula uses the [WorksheetFunction.Aggregate Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-aggregate-method-excel) to return the matching results from an array.

1.a    Assuming the list located at `'[Talent Biography Report Sample 8-8-18.xlsx]Leadership Training Info'!$A:$A` does not have blank cells in between:

```
= IFERROR( INDEX( TargetRange,
AGGREGATE( 15, 6, ROW(MatchCellColumn) / ( SourceRange = MatchCell ), 
ROWS($1:1) ) ), "" )
```

1.b    If there are blank cells in between the list located at `'[Talent Biography Report Sample 8-8-18.xlsx]Leadership Training Info'!$A:$A` use this formula:

```
= IFERROR( INDEX( TargetRange,
AGGREGATE( 15, 6, ROW(MatchCellColumn) / ( ( SourceRange <> "" ) *
( SourceRange = MatchCell ) ), 
ROWS($1:1) ) ), "" )
```

Where:
`TargetRange`:      `'[Talent Biography Report Sample 8-8-18.xlsx]Leadership Training Info'!$E:$E`
`SourceRange`:      `'[Talent Biography Report Sample 8-8-18.xlsx]Leadership Training Info'!$A:$A`
`MatchCell`:        `$B$1`
`MatchCellColumn`:  `$B:$B`

In order to return only the date of the time stamp from the `TargetRange` we should wrap the `Index` Formula above within this formula *(this solution could also be applied to the Array Formula)*:

2.a To return the date as a string, use this formula:

```
= IFERROR( TRIM( LEFT( SUBSTITUTE( INDEX( ), " ",REPT(" ",5) ), 10)  ), "" )
```

2.b To return the date as a date serial, use this formula:

```
= IFERROR( DATEVALUE( TRIM( LEFT( SUBSTITUTE( INDEX( ), " ",REPT(" ",5) ), 10) ) ), "" )
```

**Note:** *this formula will return an error (i.e. "") if the date in the time stamp cannot be recognized as a valid Excel date, i.e the time stamp date is formatted as `mm-dd-yyyy` and the system date is defined as `dd-mm-yyyy`.*

**Formulas:**

Use this formulas to return the time stamp form the list located at `'[Talent Biography Report Sample 8-8-18.xlsx]Leadership Training Info'!$A:$E`:

1. To return the time stamp, enter this formula in `E2` then copy downwards as required:

`= IFERROR( INDEX( '[Talent Biography Report Sample 8-8-18.xlsx]Leadership Training Info'!$E:$E,
AGGREGATE( 15, 6,
ROW($B:$B) / ( '[Talent Biography Report Sample 8-8-18.xlsx]Leadership Training Info'!$A:$A = $B$1 ),
ROWS($1:1) ) ), "" )`

2. To return the date as string, enter this formula in `F2` then copy downwards as required:

`= IFERROR( TRIM( LEFT( SUBSTITUTE(
INDEX( '[Talent Biography Report Sample 8-8-18.xlsx]Leadership Training Info'!$E:$E,
AGGREGATE( 15, 6,
ROW($B:$B) / ( '[Talent Biography Report Sample 8-8-18.xlsx]Leadership Training Info'!$A:$A = $B$1 ),
ROWS($1:1) ) ),
" ",REPT(" ",5) ), 10)  ), "" )`

3. To return the date as a date serial, enter this formula in `E2` then copy downwards as required

`= IFERROR( DATEVALUE( TRIM( LEFT( SUBSTITUTE(
INDEX( '[Talent Biography Report Sample 8-8-18.xlsx]Leadership Training Info'!$E:$E,
AGGREGATE( 15, 6,
ROW($B:$B) / ( '[Talent Biography Report Sample 8-8-18.xlsx]Leadership Training Info'!$A:$A = $B$1 ),
ROWS($1:1) ) ),
" ",REPT(" ",5) ), 10) ) ), "" )`

[image]

[image]